# add a button to execute a custom function in wordpress admin edit page area

Tags: wordpress

In my website when I publish a page I want to write a file representing that page's itself (content, title, url, etc). 
In my function.php I've create a function to generate the file called on event:

```
add_action ( 'publish_page', 'generateFile' );

function generateFile($pageId){
.....

}
```

The above code works well.

Now I want to call the function "generateFile" when the user press an apposite button in the admin edit page area, so I want to add a new button beside the "publish" button to call my function on click.

Is it possible? How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into post_submitbox_start action,

```
// To add button
add_action( 'post_submitbox_start', function() {
    print '<a href="path-to-plugin/generate.php">Generate file</button>';
});
```

This will add button right next to publish, or a better way of doing this would be to hook into the save_post action and grab all the details of a post through it.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. This will create a button next to "publish". How can I execute my "generateFile" inside the function.php by clicking on the new created button?

Comment: Well using a single functions.php will be a mess. Its better to create a new plugin and then assign add the function inside that plugin. Then you can also reference to a single file through the above method.